# Jquery scrollbar doesn't work for all the overflow data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried changing the style of scrollbar using nicescroll jquery plugin.
Defined following javascript for an #ID

```
<script>
  var leftbox;
  var off;

  function initScroll() {
    $("#box").scroll(function(e) {
      if (!off) return;
      leftbox.style.backgroundPosition=-px+"px "+-py+"px";
  });
}

  $(document).ready(function() {
    leftbox = document.getElementsByTagName("#leftbox")[0];
    $('#leftbox').niceScroll({cursoropacitymax:0.8,cursorwidth:8});    
    initScroll();
});
</script>
```

I thought it will change scroll bar for all the occurrences of the same #ID (#leftbox)
But it changed scrollbar for the first occurrence of #ID

Help me out!
I want this code to change the scrollbar even if I called #ID for n-times..

Comment: Where you set the `off`variable to true?

Answer (score 1):

An ID is uniqe. you cant have multiple of the same id in use. try with an class